# Add column in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

I'm trying to add an XMLType column into a table, but it returns an error. Why?

This is the query:

```
alter table TEST_ID add column xml_column xmltype;
```

It returns the error:

```
[SQL] alter table TEST_ID add column xml_column xmltype
[Err] ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't need the "column" word in there, so it's:

`ALTER TABLE test_id
   ADD xml_column xmltype;`

Answer (score 21):

In addition,

you can add multiple columns at the same time with:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (column1 VARCHAR(40), column2 Date, column3 Number);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error- key **COLUMN** is not required before **column name** :

**1. To add a single column:**

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD 
    COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE;
```

**2. To add multiple columns:**

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD (
    COLUMN_NAME1 DATA_TYPE1,
    COLUMN_NAME2 DATA_TYPE2, 
    COLUMN_NAME3 DATA_TYPE3
    .
    .
    .
);
```